# How do I dynamically add two classes using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add dynamically two classes to a button.

One class is a simple variable reference, and the other needs to use conditional logic.

Here is my code :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-xl "
  *ngFor="let node of warriorNodesList"
  [ngClass]="node.name"
  [ngClass]="{'btn-info':node.isLocked == true ,'btn-danger':node.isLocked == false}"
  (mouseover)="display($event, node)">
  <span>{{node.name}}</span>
</button>
```

The first class is the `name` property of the `node` variable:

```
*ngFor="let node of warriorNodesList"
        [ngClass]="node.name
```

The second is a conditional expression:

```
[ngClass]="{'btn-info':node.isLocked == true ,'btn-danger':node.isLocked == false}
```

How can I add all of that in only one `ngClass`? It seems that only one `ngClass` gets bound to an element and the other is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
[ngClass]="[ node.name, node.isLocked == true ? 'btn-info' : 'btn-danger' ]"
```

Comment: the first part isn't boolean "node.name" , i wanna just add this first class with its name

Comment: That's what it is supposed to do. The `true` is to add it always (unconditionally).

Comment: Angular: Parse Error: Missing expected : at column 6 in [{node.name:true,'btn-info':node.isLocked ==true,'btn-danger':node.isLocked==false}] in @21:8

Comment: Sorry, that seems to work only in Dart. I updated my answer. This should work in TS.

Comment: [ngClass]="[ node.name, node.isLocked == true ? 'btn-info' : 'btn-danger']" , "null is not accepted , would u updare ur answer like this

Comment: Right :D, didn't notice they have the same condition.